# Editing a property from within a foreach is not affecting the collection

Tags: c#, grouping

I made up a test case:

I have a table like this

```
Id|IdA|IdW|Quantity
1  1   3    5
2  1   4    2
3  2   5    3
```

`Id` is the primary key, `IdA` is the article id, `IdW` is the box id, quantity is the amount of articles.

Now I have to group by `IdA` summing the quantities, so I'm doing:

```
var groups = 
        models
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.IdA })
            .Select
            (
                x => 
                    new Model
                    { 
                        Id = (x.Select(y => y.Id).Count() > 1) ? 0 : x.Select(y => y.Id).First(), 
                        IdA = x.Key.IdA, 
                        Qty = x.Sum(y => y.Qty) 
                    }
            );
```

Here `models` is the table above. It works fine, I also managed to kept the primary key when no grouping is done (there is only one `IdA`)

Now I want to do this: I want to keep the `IdW` for the ones that haven't been grouped. The ideal result would be:

```
Id|IdA|IdW|Quantity
0  1   0    7
3  2   5    3
```

I tried to do a foreach on the groups, retrieving the row using the primary key, and then setting the `IdW` to the group, like this:

```
foreach(var e in groups)
{
    var nonGroupedRow = models.Where(x => e.Id != 0 && x.Id == e.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    var targetModel = groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == e.Id);
    if(nonGroupedRow != null && targetModel != null)
    {
        targetModel.IdW = nonGroupedRow.IdW;
    }
}
```

This incredibly is not working. Both groups still have `IdW = 0`. I also made up another test to be sure, doing:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new List<A> { new A { Id = 1 }, new A { Id = 2 } };
    a.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).Id = 2;
    // both have Id = 2
}

class A
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
}
```

It just have to work in my head, also given the example here above, yet it's not. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Should be almost the same as how you do `Id`.  And that can be shortened to `x.Count() > 1 ? 0 : x.First().Id`.

Comment: Use left outer join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your count is counting the amount of entries found in the group by so you do not need to specify it to count the id's it would be the same

Secondly same thing to retrieve the first one's Id, take the first entry from the grouped data then the id property from there

You basically had the answer

```
var groups = 
      models
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.IdA })
        .Select
        (
            x => 
                new Model
                { 
                    Id = (x.Count() > 1) ? 0 : x.First().Id, 
                    IdA = x.Key.IdA,
                    IdW = (x.Count() > 1) ? 0 : x.First().IdW,
                    Qty = x.Sum(y => y.Qty) 
                }
        );
```

Comment: Hadn't really thoguth to this! Thanks